# Green's function for a Hirsch-Farnsworth fusor

Tags: electromagnetism, greens-functions, fusion, nuclear-engineering

I'm writing a proposal for building a Hirsch-Farnsworth fusor at my university using a vacuum chamber, deuterium, and high voltage power. A loop of wire inside the chamber is set at a negative voltage with no charge which causes the positive deuterium ions to accelerate towards the center of the chamber. To calculate the fusion reaction rate and compare it with the detector readings, the Green's function for the Laplace equation due to no charge on the loop.

$$\nabla^2 \phi = 0$$

must be derived for this example to approximate the velocity of an ion as it fuses and thus the temperature.

So the workflow to compare theory to experiment would be

1. Derive the Green's function for a wire loop voltage. Assuming no interactions between deuterium ions for now.
2. Conservation of energy to find the velocity as the ions reach the center
3. Convert velocity to temperature to reactivity $<\sigma v>$ in the figure below

$v_{Ti}=\sqrt{\frac{kT_i}{m_i}}$ : ion thermal velocity

[image: reactivity]

4. Reactivity to reaction rate and thus the average reaction rate

$R_{12}=n_1n_2<\sigma v>$ : Reaction Rate

$<R_{12}>=\frac{\int R_{12} \rho(r) d^3r}{\int \rho(r) d^3r}$ : The average reaction rate

5. The average reaction rate can then be used in comparison with neutron detector data

I'm an nuclear engineer who finished the first part of Jackson EM in a course at university which is why I'm interested in using Green's functions for this problem. I believe the relevant section would involve 1.10: Formal Solution of Electrostatic Boundary-Value Problem with Green Function. Although most of the problems in the course involved either charged or grounded conducting *spheres* or *charged* wires, I cannot recall an example where we dealt with voltages on wires or I'm likely clearly missing something. If anyone has any advise I'd love you forever.

Here's some more information about Hirsch-Farnsworth fusors
https://fusor.net/files/Ligon-QED-IE.pdf